# How to create a trigger to prevent admins/devs from creating new workflow rules/process builder

Tags: process-builder, workflow

So with flows replacing process builder and workflow rules there's a problem in my org. Admins in other departments whom i'm not the boss of continue to make these, but org wide it's been stated we wont make anymore....but they still are.

So instead of playing the constant cat and mouse of checking every deployment, checking the audit trail...etc etc. I'd rather put a trigger in place blocking the creation of new workflow rules and new process builder 'processes'.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: how do they deploy these into production? Do you have source control? As Adrian answered, you won't solve the problem within Salesforce, but your release process could have checks/blockages in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you are seeking to do is not possible.